# Regular Expressions with `<` and `\?` strange matches

Tags: sed, grep, regular-expression

Assume, there is a simple test PHP script:

```
<?php
$a = ($argc == 2 ? $argv[1] : 10);
for ($i = 0; $i < $a; $i++) {
  echo '.';
}
echo PHP_EOL;
```

Now, I do a grep or a conditional sed on the file:

```
grep '<' test.php
```

yields the two lines containing the `<`. That's clear.

```
grep '\?' test.php
```

yields the two lines containing the question mark. That's clear.

```
grep '<\?' test.php
```

returns all lines - why? I expected it to output only the first line. But maybe, the `<` should be escaped, which yields another unexpected output.

```
sed -n '/pattern/p' test.php
```

yields the same results.

I tried to get an answer at https://regex101.com/, but by my surprise, the website shows what I expect. Also, a quick and dirty PHP implementation of `grep` yields what I expect:

```
<?php
if (($fh = fopen($argv[2], 'r')) !== false) {
  while ($line = fgets($fh)) {
    if (mb_ereg($argv[1], $line) !== false) echo $line;
  }
}
```

My question is: What is the reasoning behind those matches in `grep` and `sed`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`grep`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)’s default behaviour is to interpret regular expressions as [basic regular expressions](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap09.html#tag_09_03) (BREs). These don’t support `?` as a special symbol; it’s the basic character:

```
grep '<?' test.php
```

thus gives the result you’re expecting.

[GNU `grep` treats escaped versions of symbols which have special meaning in extended regular expressions but not in BREs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html#Basic-vs-Extended) as special symbols, even in BREs: thus in a BRE, `\?` has the same meaning as `?` in an ERE. So `grep '<\?'` matches zero or one `<`, which matches everything (and highlights `<` if you have colour output enabled).

The same reasoning applied to [`sed`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/sed.html).

Comment: You nailed it when mentioning Basic vs Extended RE. So, setting `-E` to grep or `-r` to sed (both GNU) does the magic. But why is it that: `grep '<\?'` matches zero or one `<` in Basic RE? Could you please expand on it?

Comment: I thought I’d addressed that in my paragraph starting with “When you escape ...”. Does that need more detail? I’ll rephrase it.

Comment: Thanks for expanding on it, now it is clear. Portable would be `<[?]`.

Comment: Indeed, `<[?]` is portable; `<?` should be too since that’s what POSIX specifies, both for `grep` and `sed`.

Comment: But `<?` means something different in ERE as in BRE, it means `<{0,1}` (which is quite useless because this matches always).

Comment: @rexkogitans, in ERE, you'd use `<\?`. In this case the backslash is fully specified, it removes the special meaning of the `?`. I don't think it's worth the trouble trying to create regexes that would have the same meaning in both BRE and ERE...